# How to read contents of a JSON file embedded as Object in Excel using C#?

Tags: c#, json, excel

I embedded a JSON file into Excel using C# like so,

```
string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties); //The string contains data in JSON format
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\PJson.json", json);
Excel.Workbook book = xlApp.ActiveWorkbook;
Excel.Worksheet sheet = book.Worksheets[11];
sheet.Shapes.AddOLEObject(Filename: @"C:\PJson.json", Height: 400, Width: 400);
```

Now, I want to write code to access this file from excel and read its contents into another string. Is this possible?